# Crontab Interval Shortcuts

Tags: cron

Are there any crontab interface "shortcuts" in any (compatible/compliant) version of cron? We run some scripts with a regular interval, but offset.

I dislike lines like this;

`3,8,13,18,23,28,33,38,43,48,53,58 * * * * command`

I believe I have tried something like;

`3/5 * * * * command`
and
`*/5+3 * * * * command` before to no avail.

Is there any way to normalize/shrink cron entries with offset schedules such as the above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
3-59/5 * * * * command
```

Should start the job at 3 minutes after the hour and run it every 5 minutes until 59 minutes after the hour.

Answer (score 3):

*/5 will get you every 5 min

3-58/5 should get you every 5 min starting at 3

http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Comment: Your source is GREAT, but aggravating that the answer to my question is not in one of the block-level examples, but is just a paragraph. (This has nothing to do with your answer, just vocalizing a chuckle I had when reading.)